# How to make an rf choke and tx rx coils?

Tags: rf, coil

I am a tinkerer and trying to make a wireless charger in which I felt difficulty in making an RF choke coil of 8.6uH , 0.674uH & 1.235uH Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: There are a number of coil calculators on line something like http://www.crystalradio.net/cal/indcal2.shtml or http://www.tuberadio.com/coils/coil3.html

Comment: Oh man...sure hope wireless charges are NOT using 14MHz ! More disaster to our HF Amateur Service Band!
Bad enough the entire RF spectrum from DC to High UHF has been destroyed by unintentional radiators found with All the lovely switch mode power supplies (that wall wart/chargers) , laptop chargers and every other Crappy, unfiltered, poorly shielded digital device being allowed (illegally) to make the RF spectrum useless for weak signal reception and high digital smpg noise floors...please tell me these charges do NOT use the MF to HF spectrum...with their rfi Also being put onto the Ac line.

Answer (score 3):

Most wireless chargers generate a magnetic field that is picked up by the portable/mobile device and converted to electricity. They use resonant coils to increase power throughput and the coils are tuned with a capacitor to make them resonant.

If you have an operating frequency of 14MHz and a coil of 8.6uH, to tune it requires a capacitance of 15.027pF and this gives you a resonant frequency of 14.001 MHz. Here's what a resonant peak would look like from an inductor and capacitor (this particular one resonates at 1500 Hz but it is no different, in principle to any other pairing of L and C): -

[image]
<sub>(source: [arachnoid.com](http://arachnoid.com/sage/graphics/electronics_complex_numbers/rlc_parallel_plot2.png))</sub>

[image]

If capacitance OR inductance increased 2% the resultant frequency would be changed by about 1% i.e. accuracy is important but maybe not as significant as you might think.

The Q of one of these resonant coils might be as high as 20 and this informs you that if the resonant frequency is 14MHz, the 3dB bandwidth is one-twentieth of this i.e. about 700kHz. This means that the power transferred at 14MHz +/-350kHz will be 3dB down.

"3dB down" isn't exactly a big problem for this type of product - if the resonant coil has drifted off by 350kHz then the charging power received by your portable might have halved.

A change in 350kHz in 14MHz is 2.5% and this will be like either the inductor or capacitor drifting off by 5%.

What I'm trying to say is that getting a coil's inductance correct to 3 decimal places is missing the point. Also, you will likely modify the tuning with small value capacitors to get it spot on 14MHz.

My advice is this. You might have a certain area in which to make a coil - it might be 6 inches diameter for instance - try winding 3 turns and putting 22pF across it and seeing where it resonates. This can be done with a signal generator and o-scope. If you don't have any test equipment then you are in the dark I'm afraid to say.